# problem with halt command to power off

Tags: command-line, shutdown

I use Ubuntu 11.10. My problem is that I cannot power off the computer with `sudo halt` command. Ubuntu shutting down screen comes and stops at there (something like the pic below). I waited about 15 minutes which is abnormally long and am obliged to press the power button to shut down. The second try was the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your problem? `halt` and `poweroff` are two different things, as explained in the `halt` manual.

You should launch it with

```
sudo halt -p
```

to poweroff it.

Anyway, from the `man halt`:

```
When called with --force or when in runlevel 0 or 6, this tool  invokes
the reboot(2) system call itself and directly reboots the system.  Oth‐
erwise this simply invokes the shutdown(8) tool  with  the  appropriate
arguments.
```

So I think that could be a good idea to use `shutdown` directly, as this:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: sudo init 0 works too